# Getting and comparing BOVW histograms for image similarity

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I'm building an image similarity program and, as I am a begginer in CV, I talked with an expert who gave me the following recommended steps to get the really basic functionality:

1. Extract keypoints (DoG, Harris, etc.) and local invariant descriptors (SIFT, SURF, etc.) from all images.
2. Cluster them to form a codebook (bag of visual words dictionary; BOVW)
3. Quantize the features from each image into a BOVW histogram
4. Compare the BOVW histograms for each image (typically using chi-squared, cosine, or euclidean distance)

The point number one is easy, but I start getting confused at step 2. This is the code I've written so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

dictionarySize = 20
BOW = cv2.BOWKMeansTrainer(dictionarySize)

for imgpath in ['testimg/testcropped1.jpg','testimg/testcropped2.jpg','testimg/testcropped3.jpg']:
    img = cv2.imread(imgpath)
    gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)

    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    kp = sift.detect(gray,None)
    kp,des = sift.compute(img,kp)

    img=cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp,img)
    cv2.imwrite('%s_keypoints.jpg' % imgpath, img)

    BOW.add(des)
```

I extract some features using SIFT and then I try to build a BOVW o each image descriptor. The problem is I have no idea if this is correct and how to get the histograms.